# Execute a Python statement in a Bash script

Tags: python, bash, shell

Is it possible to have Python evaluate a Python statement within a Bash shell script? I am thinking about something along the lines of perl's `-e` option.

The problem at hand is that I'd like to use Python's `split` function on a Bash string. I know it's doable in Bash alone, but I am curious.

Comment: Have you tried searching for e.g. [how to invoke Python from the command line](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+command+line+options&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=sb#channel=sb&q=invoking%20python%20from%20command%20line&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official)? Or even just tried `python --help`?

Comment: Have you seen [Equivalent to perl -e](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2006-October/050026.html) from the python mailing list?

Comment: And you know you can use pipes to invoke Python, just most other commands? Or have the shell do environment variable replacement?

Comment: The answer is yes, but it won't actually help you.

Comment: Can you give a concrete example of what you are trying to do? Invoking `python` to split a string sounds a bit overkill.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I have tried searching Google, but with a "Invoking Python from Bash", and all I got was "Invoking Bash from Python". And I had tried man python, and I have seen the -c option, but didn't seem to work the way I expected. Apparently I might have thought more than those two minutes.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth I hadn't thought of the Python mailing list explicitly, but thanks for the heads-up on that. The concrete example sounded silly, but I just wanted to split a path using '/' as the delimiter: the string is /path/to/something, I wanted to do something like "path/to/something".split('/').

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Yes, I am aware that you can use python with pipes, and I am aware of command substitution, but I wanted to evaluate a single statement, not having a separate python script of one line. I don't get the environment variable replacement bit, sorry.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Thanks for the comment, but you don't explain why that would not help me.

Comment: Because you'd still have to split it in bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equivalent of `perl -e` is `python -c`:

```
$ python -c "import sys;print sys.argv[1].split(',')" "foo,bar,baz"
['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Answer (score 2):

- One way could be pass the statement to python executable as argument of -c as below, this should be an equivalent of perl -e

  python -c 'print "ABC DEF HIJ".split()'
- Another possible method might be to put your python statement in a python file and pass it as argument to the command as below

  exec 'python xxx.py'

Comment: @anishsane exactly, this is why I upvoted the answer but chose the other one. Thanks anyway Lawrence.